# Accessing a class's constants

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, constants

When I have the following:

```
class Foo
   CONSTANT_NAME = ["a", "b", "c"]

  ...
end
```

Is there a way to access with `Foo::CONSTANT_NAME` or do I have to make a class method to access the value?

Answer (score 281, accepted):

What you posted should work perfectly:

```
class Foo
  CONSTANT_NAME = ["a", "b", "c"]
end

Foo::CONSTANT_NAME
# => ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: Hmm, I must have mistyped when I tested earlier.  Ooops :)

Comment: for this to truly be a constant, don't forget to add a .freeze on the end of the value!
`CONSTANT_NAME = ["a", "b", "c"].freeze`

Comment: Always mix up `::` and `.` ;)

Comment: Things are hard to spot when uppercased ;)

Comment: @Nick what is the rule? when should I use `.` and when `::`? thx

Comment: @wuarmin I believe that `::` is for module/class level thing (so in the above, CONSTANT_NAME is a class "static" property). You'd also use it for module namespacing eg `ActiveRecord::Base`. The `.` is used for instance properties and methods (eg `Foo.new`). Although I believe you can use `.` to call static methods... There is a lot of discussion about it on SO.. Eg: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11043499/224707

Answer (score 53):

Some alternatives:

```
class Foo
  MY_CONSTANT = "hello"
end

Foo::MY_CONSTANT
# => "hello"

Foo.const_get :MY_CONSTANT
# => "hello"

x = Foo.new
x.class::MY_CONSTANT
# => "hello"

x.class.const_defined? :MY_CONSTANT
# => true

x.class.const_get :MY_CONSTANT
# => "hello"
```

Answer (score 51):

If you're writing additional code within your class that contains the constant, you can treat it like a global.

```
class Foo
  MY_CONSTANT = "hello"

  def bar
    MY_CONSTANT
  end
end

Foo.new.bar #=> hello
```

If you're accessing the constant outside of the class, prefix it with the class name, followed by two colons

```
Foo::MY_CONSTANT  #=> hello
```

Answer (score 18):

> Is there a way to access `Foo::CONSTANT_NAME`?

Yes, there is:

```
Foo::CONSTANT_NAME
```

Comment: When i am trying to access it, i am having below warning. warning: already initialized constant TestData::CONSTANT_VAR      This variable is not initialized anywhere else. Why i am having this warning?