# collection select out of a constant in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

There is a constant called `ENVIRONMENTS`

```
validates :environment, inclusion: ENVIRONMENTS
```

with these associated constants and strings

```
ENVIRONMENT_INTERNAL="internal"
ENVIRONMENT_STAGING="staging"
ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION="production"
ENVIRONMENTS=[ENVIRONMENT_INTERNAL,ENVIRONMENT_STAGING,ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION]
```

I am trying to build a collection select which shows the strings related to the constants. How do I do it? This is how I have tried to do it

```
  =f.input :envrionment, as: :select, collection: [ENVIRONMENTS]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to access initialise the constant via the model;

```
  =f.select :environment, Deployment::ENVIRONMENTS, include_blank: 'Select'
```

this link proved useful [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427548/how-do-you-access-a-class-constant-variables)

Answer (score 0):

`f.select` might come in handy here, as I have not used more of `collection_select`

```
<%= f.select 'server_id', ENVIRONMENTS, {:include_blank => "Select"} %>
```

`value` would be name as the `selected` entity

An ex:

```
<option value="internal">internal</option>
```