# Classes with the same name results in uninitialized constant when using Rails 6 Zeitwerk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, zeitwerk

I'm having issues with [zeitwerk](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html) where I can't access another models constant that shares the same name. For example:

in `/app/models` I have a `worker.rb` file with a constant `RETRY_COUNT`

```
class Worker < ApplicationRecord
  RETRY_COUNT = 10
end
```

and in `/lib` I have a `/critical/worker.rb` file but namespaced under `critical`

```
module Critical
  class Worker
    some_method(::Worker::RETRY_COUNT)
  end
end
```

I'm able to call the worker model class using `::Worker`, but when I call `::RETRY_COUNT`, it results in

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Worker (call 'Worker.connection' to establish a connection)::RETRY_COUNT
```

Anyway around this? I could just hardcode the `RETRY_COUNT` on the `Critical::Worker` class but I'd like to avoid doing that.

Comment: `::Worker.const_get(:RETRY_COUNT)` might help?

Comment: @JoshBrody that didn't work. Any way around getting a constant results in the same error

Comment: alternatives I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/33489452/4852449

Answer (score 0):

Based on your updates, I'm fairly certain you have a circular dependency. `has_many` calls are processed during  "ApplicationRecord initialization".  During "AR initialization", one of them references `Critical::Worker.foo` in a `has_many`, which references `::Worker` (an AR) for `RETRY_COUNT`, which isn't done initializing yet.

If you need this value for "AR initialization time", then put it in a file that has no other dependencies.

```rb
module Independent # no other dependencies in this file
  RETRY_COUNT = 10
end
```

Then:

```rb
class Worker < ApplicationRecord
  RETRY_COUNT = Independent::RETRY_COUNT
end

module Critical
  class Worker
    RETRY_COUNT = Independent::RETRY_COUNT
  end
end
```

Zeitgeist should then be able to figure out it needs to load `Independent` before anything else, like your AR classes.

Comment: Unfortunately neither of those worked. The first one resulted in `uninitialized constant #<Class:0x00007fa7a0097be0>:: RETRY_COUNT ` and the second one resulted in `undefined method `retry_count' for Critical::Worker:Class (NoMethodError)

Comment: I probably should have mentioned the RETRY_COUNT is being called in a method in class (like `has_many`), see edited post

Comment: Oh, I think I see what's happening. Updated my answer with new information.